# Clang scan-build won't work with Xcode 4.2 LLVM 3.0 build configuration

Tags: xcode, llvm, clang, clang-static-analyzer

I've installed Xcode 4.2 final version to be able to compile for iOS 5.

We are using Jenkins for CI and run Clang scan-build from the llvm.org project page. (Version 258) The project is configured to use LLVM 3.0 (which is default since Xcode 4.2). Now every time I try to run scan-build do I get following error:

```
CompileC build/Cortado.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cortado.build/Objects-normal/i386/TPContentDetailViewController_iPad.o Classes/iPad/TPContentDetailViewController_iPad.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd "/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado"
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/android-sdk-mac_x86/android-ndk-r6b:/Applications/android-sdk-mac_x86/platform-tools:/Applications/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools:/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Tools:/Volumes/Sources/Tools:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin"
    /Users/thwee/Downloads/checker-258/libexec/ccc-analyzer -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-print-source-range-info -fdiagnostics-show-category=id -fdiagnostics-parseable-fixits -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -DDEBUG -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40100 -iquote "/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Cortado.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cortado.build/Cortado-generated-files.hmap" "-I/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Cortado.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cortado.build/Cortado-own-target-headers.hmap" "-I/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Cortado.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cortado.build/Cortado-all-target-headers.hmap" -iquote "/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Cortado.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cortado.build/Cortado-project-headers.hmap" "-I/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include" "-I/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Cortado.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cortado.build/DerivedSources/i386" "-I/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Cortado.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cortado.build/DerivedSources" "-F/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" -include "/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/Cortado_Prefix.pch" -MMD -MT dependencies -MF "/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Cortado.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cortado.build/Objects-normal/i386/TPContentDetailViewController_iPad.d" -c "/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/Classes/iPad/TPContentDetailViewController_iPad.m" -o "/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Cortado.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cortado.build/Objects-normal/i386/TPContentDetailViewController_iPad.o"
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-sign-conversion"
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-fdiagnostics-print-source-range-info"
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-fdiagnostics-show-category=id"
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-fdiagnostics-parseable-fixits"
```

If I use the static code analyze of Xcode self I get following output which works without issues:

```
CompileC build/Cortado.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cortado.build/Objects-normal/i386/TPInfoCell.o Classes/TPInfoCell.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd "/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado"
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-print-source-range-info -fdiagnostics-show-category=id -fdiagnostics-parseable-fixits -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -DDEBUG -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40100 -iquote "/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Cortado.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cortado.build/Cortado-generated-files.hmap" "-I/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Cortado.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cortado.build/Cortado-own-target-headers.hmap" "-I/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Cortado.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cortado.build/Cortado-all-target-headers.hmap" -iquote "/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Cortado.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cortado.build/Cortado-project-headers.hmap" "-I/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include" "-I/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Cortado.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cortado.build/DerivedSources/i386" "-I/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Cortado.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cortado.build/DerivedSources" "-F/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" -include /var/folders/m7/1lwxj7113xb17b8k635bn0200000gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/Cortado_Prefix-curmpedgpezkvsgarfuwvmdrauwa/Cortado_Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF "/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Cortado.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cortado.build/Objects-normal/i386/TPInfoCell.d" -c "/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/Classes/TPInfoCell.m" -o "/Volumes/Sources/Starteam - Main View/Workplace/Cortado/build/Cortado.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cortado.build/Objects-normal/i386/TPInfoCell.o"
```

Has someone an idea what I can do to get scan-build running again without disabling LLVM 3.0 use?!

Answer (score 5):

Found a solution to have checker-258 build :

Pass this param to scan-build : --use-cc=`which clang`

Then to make it builds by jenkins and the scan-build plugin... it's a little trickier :

Move scan-build to scan-build.bin, and then make scan-build be a script :

```
#!/bin/sh

dir=$(dirname $0)
$dir/scan-build.bin --use-cc=`which clang` $@
```

The result of `which clang` is : /usr/bin/clang

Edit: worked for two projects, one with LLVM 3.0, the other with llvm-gcc4.2.

Comment: Very nice. This works for me. Thank you for your investigation of this issue.

Comment: Wow, superb answer! Note that above the command --use-cc=which clang needs backticks (Stack Overflow's mark-up language interpreted the backtick characters as formatting). So it should look like this: `--use-cc='which clang'` (replace apostrophe (') with backtick character (accent grave; ascii character 96).

Answer (score 1):

I raised a bug with Apple about this and other issues (like scan-build not recognising ARC'd code).

The fix is to install checker-260, see http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/release_notes.html plus this modification to ccc-analyzer - http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=rev&revision=149094. Hopefully the fix to ccc-analyzer will be incorporated into a future release of scan-build.

Using this latest version of scan-build will avoid you having to make the modifications to scan-build described in the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like scan-build is deciding to use llvm-gcc, which is confusing Xcode because it is expecting to be running clang.  Probably just a bug in scan-build; I'd suggest sending an email to cfe-dev.

Comment: Okay, I will try it with an mail to cfe-dev. Thanks

Comment: cfe-dev ask me to wait until they fix this issue. problem is, that scan-build doesn't scan if the current Xcode project setting configured to use llvm or gcc. scan-build use every time gcc or g++ depending what you set up in the command line. :/ so I have to reconfigure my project settings to use gcc or disable scan-build in jenkins. :/